# Join 2 pandas dataframe on nearest but not after date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 2 dataframes that i want to join base on date value and id:
df_1

| col_1 | date_1 | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-1-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-1-2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-1-3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2023-1-4 | 3 |

df_2

| col_2 | date_2 | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2023-1-1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2023-1-1 | 2 |
| 7 | 2023-1-4 | 1 |
| 8 | 2023-1-9 | 3 |

I want to join these 2 dataframes, on the condition below:

1. df_1.id = df_2.id
2. date_1 is later than or equal to date_2
3. the distince between date_1 and date_2 is the minimum among all available date_2 fits the condition above.
   4)left outer join

The output should be:

| col_1 | date_1 | id | col_2 | date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-1-1 | 1 | 5 | 2023-1-1 |
| 2 | 2023-1-2 | 1 | 5 | 2023-1-1 |
| 3 | 2023-1-3 | 2 | 6 | 2023-1-1 |
| 4 | 2023-1-4 | 3 | NaN | NaN |

I triyed to use pd.merge_asof(df_1,df_2,by='id',direction='backward') but don't right.

Comment: maybe 2 steps: first query the qualified part of df_2, secondly merge them.

Answer (score 1):

### `merge_asof`

```
# Change dtypes to datetime
df_1['date_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['date_1'])
df_2['date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['date_2'])

pd.merge_asof(
    df_1.sort_values('date_1'), 
    df_2.sort_values('date_2'),
    by='id', left_on='date_1', 
    right_on='date_2', direction='backward'
)
```

Result

```
  col_1     date_1 id col_2     date_2
0     1 2023-01-01  1     5 2023-01-01
1     2 2023-01-02  1     5 2023-01-01
2     3 2023-01-03  2     6 2023-01-01
3     4 2023-01-04  3   NaN        NaT
```

Notes

- Both left and right dataframe must be sorted by on key
- `direction=backward` selects the last row in the right dataframe whoes on key is less than or equal to the on key of left dataframe.